# NullPointerException when using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I had an error message on the android screen. Here is the Logcat -

```
02-08 09:33:42.471: E/AndroidRuntime(11592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver something.MainActivity$CancelReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why is program working correctly after the error log? (Program is not killed)
when it throws broadcast first time, this error appears.

This is part of my code

```
public static class CancelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intents) {

            intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            String OKorNOT = intents.getExtras().getString("OKorNOT");
            String str = intents.getExtras().getString("something");

            if(OKorNOT.equals("OK")){
                //OKの場合

                tv2.setText(str);
                //this line may throws error.tv means TextView object findview already.
            }else if(OKorNOT.equals("NOT")){
                //NOTの場合
                tv.setText("yeah");//this line also throws error
                pushB.setText("NO!");   
                tv2.setText("");
            }
```

what is wrong?

edited.
this onReceive is in static class.

and around oncreate about tv,tv2 is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   static TextView tv;
   static TextView tv2;
   static Button pushB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         pushB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
         tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
         tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
}
}
```

i did defined object in onCreate.

Comment: You can just open debug mode and find out which is the null pointer.

Comment: @user2027811 Would you like to provide any feedback? If you tried my edited answer, did it work for you?

Comment: @A--C still i cant. Im getting another work-.-

Comment: @A--C and onemore. InputMainActivity == MainActivity.sorry.

Comment: And iknow now, tv.settext()in another method works right.only  in onReceive, tv,tv2 is null.

Comment: @user2027811 You need to post your full code (not just parts) if you want me to help you resolve your issue. Also post an updated version of your Logs since you did say that `InputMainActivity` is the same class as `MainActivity`